How to better organize customer identifiers?
I've come in to managing a microsoft sql azure (12.0) server and need a little help with a table.  I've worked as a data analyst for several years so understand some basic ideas with server management, but don't have full time knowledge as a DBA/engineer.
I have a table that contains contact information for our customers something like this.  All of the contacts are listed with their contact information and then a few fields identifying what sort of contact they are.  Contacts can have 0 or more identifiers.



Name
email
PhoneNumber
Primary
MonthlyUpdates
Accounting




John
jsmith@gmail.com
1234567890
0
1
0


Joe
jdoe@gmail.com
0987654312
0
0
0


Jill
jcruz@gmail.com
0197485236
1
0
1



This seems clunky and I'm concerned about additional identifiers (for example "IT Contact" or "On-Site Contact") for the contacts because right now that means adding additional columns and making the table wider.
Is there a better way to organize this table so that it's narrower and can better handle adding more contact identifiers?

A documented pattern you can use is the Entity–attribute–value model, where the Entity column is the Primary Key value of each record on the table you shared with us in your question.
Another approach is to create a XML column on the table and the define custom identifiers inside an XML XSD Collection and save the XML collection on the XML column of the table. See here how to save XML on a SQL Server table.
